# IP replacement in CodeIgniter config

Tags: php, codeigniter, ip, config

I have a big trouble with accessing to the CodeIgniter application via local network. How to put local server IP to the base_url when I come to the web-app via local network and how to put server remote IP in other case when I come through internet?

When i come from Internet:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://1.1.1.1/';
```

In other case, when i come from network where server is:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://192.168.1.222/';
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to use `http://localhost/`?

Comment: Have you try to leave it blank? `$config['base_url'] = '';`

Comment: Did you try to use http://localhost/ - nope

Have you try to leave it blank? $config['base_url'] = ''; - it's not safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this solutions and it's help :) maybe it can help somebody.

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://" . preg_match("/192\.168\./",$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? "LOCAL IP" : "REMOTE IP";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one,

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help :(